# Using Eclipse to remotely debug with gdbserver

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging, gdbserver

Does anyone know why I can't use Eclipse CDT to remotely debug a device when I manage it on the command-line with gdb using target remote command? I do get a warning when connecting, but other than that it seems to work fine.

With Eclipse I should have the correct settings and gdbserver informs me on the remote machine that a connection was establised but after that Eclipse gives an error: 'Launching  Debug' has encountered a problem. The request failed: Target is not responding (timed out). Remote device also says "Killing inferior" (which I don't get with gdb). The error log shows nothing else either.

I am using the same process, binary and gdb executable in both cases and connecting to the same device & port. I'm using gdb 7.1 and the host is 64-bit Ubuntu Lucid.

Comment: did my answer helped or solved your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685104/remote-debugging-c-applications-with-eclipse-cdt-rse-rdt My answer quite detailed and fully tested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45658783/895245

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and found that iptables was generating issues.

Have you tried stopping or disabling your firewall? In case of iptables you have to do:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

On the other hand, after you start your application (before connecting your debugger) have you checked the debug port availability through netstat?

```
#On linux
netstat -nap

#On windows
netstat -nab
```

Hope to help.